# How to check if div class exists three times or more by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to check if div with the class child exists three times or more by jQuery?

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you plan to use jQuery in your projects, it pays to first spend some time perusing the [complete list of jQuery methods and properties](http://api.jquery.com/) - an hour or two spent making a note of methods that seem useful could save you lots of hours in the future, and the brief summary of each method/property on that page has enough information to answer this question. Incidentally, this is a one-line operation even without jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the number of div with the class child by using .length
2. Use condition for need

```js
console.log($('.child').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
    <div class="child">Text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.child').length >= 3) {
  //Do stuff
}
```

Something like this should work.